# How to Retrieve Flutter Dart List Value from List Using List Value Foreign Key id from Second List

Tags: list, sqlite, dictionary, flutter, dart

Thank you in advance for your help. I have an sqlite db for my flutter app which contains a few tables. One of my tables contains two foreign keys which are id's from the other two tables' primary keys.

```
//Create Tables
  await db
      .execute('CREATE TABLE Account(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, AccountName TEXT NOT NULL, Icon INTEGER NOT NULL, CurrencyType TEXT NOT NULL, ' + 'Balance REAL NOT NULL, ' + 'IsPrimary TEXT NULL)');
  await db.execute('CREATE TABLE Budget(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, BudgetName TEXT NOT NULL, Icon INTEGER NOT NULL, Amount REAL NOT NULL, ' + 'IsPrimary TEXT NULL)');
  await db.execute('CREATE TABLE Transactions(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Account_id INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
      'Budget_id INTEGER NOT NULL, Icon INTEGER NOT NULL, Type TEXT NOT NULL,Amount REAL NOT NULL, Date TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
      'Party TEXT NOT NULL, Note TEXT NULL, ' +
      'FOREIGN KEY(Account_id) REFERENCES Account(id), ' +
      'FOREIGN KEY(Budget_id) REFERENCES Budget(id))');

//Retrieve Data
Future<List<Account>> getAccounts() async {
final db = await database;
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('Account', where: 'id NOT IN (1)');
return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
  return Account(
    maps[i]['id'],
    maps[i]['AccountName'],
    maps[i]['Icon'],
    maps[i]['CurrencyType'],
    maps[i]['Balance'],
    maps[i]['IsPrimary'],
  );
});
}

Future<List<Budget>> getBudgets() async {
final db = await database;
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('Budget', where: 'id NOT IN (1,2)');
return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
  return Budget(
    maps[i]['id'],
    maps[i]['BudgetName'],
    maps[i]['Icon'],
    maps[i]['Amount'],
    maps[i]['IsPrimary'],
  );
});
}

Future<List<Transactions>> getTransactions() async {
final db = await database;
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('Transactions');
return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
  return Transactions(
    maps[i]['id'],
    maps[i]['Type'],
    maps[i]['Amount'],
    maps[i]['Party'],
    maps[i]['Date'],
    maps[i]['Budget_id'],
    maps[i]['Account_id'],
    maps[i]['Note'],
    maps[i]['Icon'],
  );
});
}

//Variables and Method in my Stateful Widget
List<Transactions> transactions = List<Transactions>();
List<Account> accounts = List<Account>();
List<Budget> budgets = List<Budget>();

Future showTransactions() async {
accounts = await DbHelper.db.getAccounts();
transactions = await DbHelper.db.getTransactions();
budgets = await DbHelper.db.getBudgets();
setState(() {
  transactions = transactions;
  accounts = accounts;
  budgets = budgets;
});
}
```

I have a screen that shows the entered transactions but I am having trouble displaying in a Text widget the AccountName and BudgetName tied to the transactions.

Is there a way I can retrieve the AccountName and BudgetName from the Accounts and Budget Lists that I initialize in my Transactions Screen using the Account_id and Budget_id foreign keys in the transactions list? Or do I need to create another query to do this? I have the transactions in a ListView.Builder. I have no issues retrieving the transaction data but just need to grab the Account and Budget names from the other lists using the foreign keys.

Again, thanks for the help. I'm terrible with Lists and Maps and their associated methods and properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to write a helper functions which loops through 'accounts' and 'budgets' to match the `Account_id` and `Budget_id` respectively and then get the names from the Account and Budget that matches the id. Something like this:

```
String getAccountName(acc_id_in_selected_transaction){
    for (Account a in accounts){
        if(a.Account_Id == acc_id_in_selected_transaction){
            return a.AccountName;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the **`acc_id_in_selected_transaction`** is `transactions[i]['Account_id']`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and help. My brain has been fried trying to work this out. I'll give this a shot this evening and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I wasn't able to edit my comment above so this comment expands on the previous one. I was thinking I would have to use indexOf(), elementAt() or where() together somehow. I tried all these funky variations with no luck. I was hoping to avoid a loop for every index but this may be my only solution.